# laravel 6 Call to undefined function Facuz\Theme\array_get()

Tags: laravel

With laravel 6 theme and asset management package `Facuz\Theme package`

> return   an errot Call to undefined function Facuz\Theme\array_get()

```
return is_null($key) ? $this->themeConfig : array_get($this->themeConfig, $key);
```

Comment: https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-8-deprecates-string-and-array-helpers

Comment: now you can use new laravel 7.x compitable package .
https://github.com/imajkumar/laravel-theme-management

Answer (score 9):

This appears to be a breaking change in Laravel 6.0

5.6 - Uses the following

```
array = ['products' => ['desk' => ['price' => 100]]];

$price = array_get($array, 'products.desk.price');
```

6.0 - Uses the following

```
$array = ['products' => ['desk' => ['price' => 100]]];

$price = Arr::get($array, 'products.desk.price');
```

https://laravel.com/docs/6.0/helpers#method-array-get

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-array-get

It looks like this call is only used in 3 places in the codebase:

https://github.com/FaCuZ/laravel-theme/search?q=array_get&unscoped_q=array_get

Answer: Try update the calls in the package to match 6.0 ( Assuming there is no other breaking changes) this should work. If it works im sure a lot of people would be thankful for the pull request.

Comment: I have pull requested too . it working fine..
as now I have updated  and publish own package.
https://github.com/imajkumar/laravel-theme-management

Comment: depending on how where you use it you might need to add ` \ ` so it looks like this `\Arr::get()`

Answer (score 6):

Laravel 6.x and 7.x uses `Arr::get()` equivalent to `array_get()`.To use it add the [array facade](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/helpers#method-array-get) on the top of your controller or php file 
`use Illuminate\Support\Arr;`

```
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;

$array = ['products' => ['desk' => ['price' => 100]]];
$price = Arr::get($array, 'products.desk.price');
```

[For more info on laravel 6.x arrays and helpers](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/helpers#method-array-get)

Answer (score 1):

`array_get()` function has been deprecated in Laravel 6.
You sholud use `Arr::get()` instead of `array_get()`.

**Note:** you should import `use Illuminate\Support\Arr;` before using `Arr::get()` at top of the file.